# Declaring dependency inside RequireJS module

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I have 2 separate RequireJS module files as below

In my MainViewModel.js, I have

```
myFilters.init(myFilterPanelViewModel);
```

In pages/myFilters.js, I have

```
define(['viewModels/myFilterPanelViewModel'],
    function(myFilterPanelViewModel ) {
        var myFilters = {
            "init": function(myFilterPanelViewModel){

            }
        };
        return myFilters;


});
```

My question is I am calling init method from MainViewModel.js, passing an instance of myFilterPanelViewModel

So in myFilters.js module, should I need to have it declared as dependency or since I am passing myFilterPanelViewModel to the init function, the same is not required to be declared as dependency inside myFilters.js ?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly: no, the `viewModels/myFilterPanelViewModel` dependency is not needed inside myFilters.js because only the value passed as a parameter of `init` will end up being visible (suggestion: improve your naming strategy, don't use the same variable name for two different things)

Answer (score 0):

In the code that you show in your question you could indeed omit the `'viewModels/myFilterPanelViewModel'` dependency and your code should work just fine, provided that you call your `init` function with a value which is exactly the same as the module loaded with the dependency `'viewModels/myFilterPanelViewModel'`.